# OpenCV mat::at throwing exception

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opencv

This code only throws an exception in Debug mode. In Release, it gives the expected output of 0.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Mat image;
    image = Mat::zeros(5,5,CV_8UC1);
    try{
       cout<< image.at<unsigned int>(1,1)<<"\n";
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
       cout<< ex.msg;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The text of the exception thrown is

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 <
>   (unsigned)si ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) <
>   (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel s()) &&
>   ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 <<
>   3 ) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file
>   c:\users\tim\document
>   s\code\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537

Version of OpenCV is 2.4.6, and the executable is dynamically linked to the debug library.

Comment: I'm not an OpenCv expert, but maybe you are defining your Matrix elements as `unsigned char` but you're asking for an `unsigned int` And what's at mat.hpp, line 537?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the template parameter to unsigned char makes the program output nothing (No exception either)

Comment: Line 533 to 539 of Mat.hpp is `template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}`

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on that assert and see which clause of that expression is `false`?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that. Will VS go through each clause sequentially?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The exception happened because you defined image as array of unsigned char but used unsigned int inside at<> function. at<> must get same type as your matrix, i.e. unsigned char. Otherwise it throws an exception you see.
2. When you providing unsigned char to cout function, it assumes that you are trying to print a character (char) not a number. If you want to see its numeric value cast it to int:

   cout << (int)image.at < unsigned char > (1,1) << "\n";